# jQuery select items which parents are not of a given class

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can select all nodes with class "myClass" whose parent nodes don't have class "myClass".

for example, i have following HTML:

```
<div class="myContainer">
    <div class="myClass" id="d1"> 
        <div class="myClass" id="d2"></div>
        <div class="myClass" id="d4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="myClass" id="d3"></div>
</div>
```

and i want to get a list of elements with ids "d1" and "d3"

actually, i'm trying to write a code that converts HTML from that example to a list with tabulations, such as:

```
d1
  d2
  d4
d3
```

(there can be more descedant nodes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have come up with a number of possible solutions. Maybe:

```
$(":not(.myClass) > .myClass")
```

Or if you want to look beyond the direct parent:

```
$(":not(.myClass) .myClass")
```

This might work also:

```
$(".myClass:has(:not(.myClass))")
```

A better solution for your exact example:

```
$(".myContainer > .myClass")
```

Comment: thanks. the first solution is better because i'm not sure that there is always a parent node with class "myContainer"

Comment: `$(":not(.myClass) .myClass")` doesn't work (selects everything), but `$(".myClass").not('.myClass .myClass');` does. Probably because myClass is a child of myContainer.